# Tomcat: Liferay problem with portlet running

Tags: tomcat, liferay, portlet

I have an
 `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.liferay.taglib.aui.FieldWrapperTag cannot be cast to javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.Tag`
exception. The portlet does't run, there is nothing I can do about it.

I am using Liferay 6.0.6 and Spring Portlet MVC 3.0.5

Any help highly appreciated.

Bob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of problems are often caused by classloading issues. Specifically having same classes loaded by multiple classloaders.

Make sure your WAR doesn't include jsp-api.jar in WEB-INF/lib directory.